# Can't change the layout border color

Tags: java, swing, layout, colors, border

I'm doing a simple Swing layout (see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cccyU.jpg)) but for some reason no matter what I try I cannot change the colors of the 'borders' that split the three sections of the UI. Am I missing something?

The layout is done using GroupLayout.

EDIT:

The green portions are each individual JPanels contained within a GroupLayout.

I have tried background, and foreground colors, on any objects where it would make sense. I have tried applying EmptyBorder to each of the jpanels and still no luck. I think it might have to do with the layout but I'm not even sure about that.

Here is the relevent layout code. Note that this was all auto-generated by Netbeans:

```
    javax.swing.GroupLayout pnlTopLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(pnlTop);
        pnlTop.setLayout(pnlTopLayout);
        pnlTopLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            pnlTopLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 532, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        pnlTopLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            pnlTopLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 59, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

javax.swing.GroupLayout pnlSideLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(pnlSide);
        pnlSide.setLayout(pnlSideLayout);
        pnlSideLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            pnlSideLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 200, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        pnlSideLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            pnlSideLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 214, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

javax.swing.GroupLayout pnlMainLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(pnlMain);
        pnlMain.setLayout(pnlMainLayout);
        pnlMainLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            pnlMainLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 326, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        pnlMainLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            pnlMainLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 214, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(pnlSide, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(pnlMain, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addComponent(pnlTop, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 532, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(pnlTop, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 59, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(pnlMain, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(pnlSide, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
        );
```

Comment: This question is unanswerable unless you have some example code. What have you tried?

Comment: EDIT: Updated to include some layout code

Comment: @tleCan, You should edit your tags to include "swing".

Comment: @tleCan, Do you want the ability to change the color of the gray area? If so, that has nothing to do with the borders of your `JPanel`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be setting the background color of either the container's content pane, or the `JComponent` that overlays it (e.g. `JPanel`).

---

```
public final class Demo {
    private static BufferedImage bi;
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            loadImage();
            
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    createAndShowGUI();             
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // handle exception
        }
    }
    
    private static void loadImage() throws IOException{
        bi = ImageIO.read(Demo.class.getResource("../resources/whitefro1.jpg"));
    }
    
    private static void createAndShowGUI(){
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.BLUE.darker()); // here
        
        final JLabel labelOne = new JLabel();
        labelOne.setIcon(new ImageIcon(bi));
        final JLabel labelTwo = new JLabel();
        labelTwo.setIcon(new ImageIcon(bi));
        
        panel.add(labelOne);
        panel.add(labelTwo);
        frame.add(panel);       
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[image]

---

As you can see, the area between is colored a darker shade of blue.

Comment: Perfect that did it! Thanks! What is the difference between doing this.setBackground... on the JFrame and this.getContentPane().setBackground...?

Comment: Apparently it won't let me for an hour. I'll come back to check it though. Thanks again.

Comment: Sadly that does not work. All three of the jpanels that occupy the jframe already have their background colors set. It works great but it still shows the gray splitters

Comment: @tleCan, Even if you set the background color of the `JFrame` using `frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLUE.darker())`?

Comment: @tleCan, If this worked, please accept this answer by clicking the check-mark. The content pane is the gray area that you were seeing. It contains your all your `JPanel` instances.